# What does top down and bottom up approaches mean?

Tags: image-processing, object-detection

I came across top down and bottom up approaches while reading this paper
"https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.08050" on image processing.

I got a vague about top down approach from this paragraph:
"top-down approach: apply a separately trained human detector (based on object detection techniques such as the ones we discussed before), find each person, and then run pose estimation on every detection."

But couldn't understand bottom up approach from this:
"bottom-up approaches recognize human poses from pixel-level image evidence directly. They can solve both problems above: when you have information from the entire picture you can distinguish between the people, and you can also decouple the runtime from the number of people on the frame… at least theoretically."
Please help me understand these concepts. Thank you.

Both paragraph's are from this blog : "https://medium.com/neuromation-blog/neuronuggets-understanding-human-poses-in-real-time-b73cb74b3818"

Answer (score 4):

There are two person in the picture. all human has 15 joint(key point)

- Top-down approach

  1. find two bounding boxes including each person
  2. estimate human joint(15 key-point) per each bounding box

In this example, Top-down approach need pose estimation twice.

- Bottom-up approach

  1. estimate all human joint(30 key-point) in the picture
  2. classify which joint(15 key-point) are included in the same person

In this example, pose estimator doesn't care how many people are in the picture. they only consider how they can classify each joint to the each person.

In general situation, Top-down approach consume time much more than Bottom-up, because Top-down approach need N-times pose estimation by person detector results.